# Django: no migrations apply, but I have unapplied migrations

Tags: python, django, social-auth-app-django

I deleted my database and tried to create a new one.
I did:

1. `python manage.py makemigrations`
2. `python manage.py migrate`

Then I ran `python manage.py runserver` and it returned

```
You have 2 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): social_django.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
```

Then I ran `python manage.py migrate` and it returned

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions, social_django
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

I am using django 3.0.7 and social-auth-app-django 4.0.0

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to disable the environment.

I don't know why.

Comment: What does that mean

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see which migrations have been done by viewing your database with whichever program you use to do that. And checking the django_migrations table.

The migrations that need to be applied will still be in the migrations folders for the apps that haven't been updated.
To get them migrated, assuming they're still in your installed_apps in your settings.py, simply delete the migrations (probably `__init__.py`) from the migrations folders and re-run :

```
> python manage.py makemigrations
> python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: Now django doesn’t print `You have 2 unapplied migration(s)', but the model still not working.

Comment: Ok, then you'll have to go into the table django_migrations, and delete the rows for the missing apps.  i.e. delete the 0001_initial and any subsequent migrations if they exist. Django will then be able to recognize that they are missing.

Comment: now `python manage.py migrate` fails with `model_state = state.models[app_label, self.name_lower]` 
`KeyError: ('social_django', 'association')`

Comment: That sounds like a refactoring issue. You might have to restore the 0001 initial migration file for that app, and change whatever name was changed, back to the original and run makemigrations again.

Comment: I returned the modified file and returned to the first error (`You have 2 unapplied migration(s).`)

Answer (score 0):

run the following command on your command prompt:

```
1.python manage.py migrate
2.python manage.py runserver
```

[image]